# $|x_i|$ is the smallest number $z_i$ that satisfies $x_i \leq z_i$ and $-x_i \leq z_i$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-programming, absolute-value

I'm a bit ashamed that I have a math degree and can't figure out this seemingly simple problem, but that's what the situation is. From *Introduction to Linear Optimization* by Bertsimas and Tsitsiklis, they mention on p. 18 that

> $|x_i|$ is the smallest number $z_i$ that satisfies $x_i \leq z_i$ and $-x_i \leq z_i$

**How does one prove this**?

I wish I could provide some more context to this, but this statement seems to have been mentioned as a side comment. We don't know anything other than that $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

I do know that by definition (and I have to admit, it is confusing that they use $z_i$ to represent $|x_i|$ as well):

$$|x_i| = \begin{cases}
x_i, & x_i \geq 0 \\
-x_i, & x_i < 0\text{.}
\end{cases}$$
I believe what we're trying to prove is that
$$|x_i| = \min\{z_i \mid x_i \leq z_i, -x_i \leq z_i\}\text{.}$$
However, I'm not sure how to derive this from the definition of $|x_i|$ given above.

Comment: Is anything special about the subscript $i$?

Comment: @Clayton Nah. It's just a component of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I figured I should keep the notation as is, should someone have the same question I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z=\min\{z_i \mid x_i \leq z_i, -x_i \leq z_i\}\text{.}$ Let us also get rid of the index $i$ of $x_i$: I will denote it $x$.

First, we have $x\leq |x|$ and $-x\leq |x|$, which can be established simply by a disjonction of cases (depending on whether $x$ is negative or non-negative). Hence, by definition, $z\leq |x|$.

Second, we know that $z\geq \max(x,-x)$ by definition. But we have the identity $\max(x,-x)=|x|$ which again may be shown by disjonction of cases.

We conclude that $|x|=z$.

Comment: Well, $z$ is defined as the minimum of a set, which contains $|x|$ ...

Comment: Ah right, I was reading your argument incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The only comment I have is that it wasn't obvious to me how to use proof by disjunction to prove $x \leq |x|$ and $-x \leq |x|$, so I ended up just using $|x| = \max(-x, x)$, from which those inequalities follow trivially.